# Force video in center with other content on either side

Tags: html, css

So I have this:

```
<h2 id="vtitle">...</h2>
<video ...></video>
<h3 id="vdescription">...</h3>
```

And every element in there is inline-block. It comes out as expected:[image]

But I want to know how I can force the video in the center and the title and description be relative to that. How can I do this?

EDIT: I should have been more specific. I want the video to be in the exact center, and no matter the size of the title and comments, the video will always be in the exact center and the title and description to either side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can do it like this ([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/e7vv62x8/))

HTML:

```
<h1>Main Title</h1>
<div id="wrapper">
<h2>Video title</h2>
<video></video>
<h3> Video description Video description Video description Video description Video description Video description Video description Video description Video description Video description Video description</h3>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
text-align: center;
}

#wrapper {
width: 100%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
}

video {    
height: 150px;
background-color: #ccc;
margin: 0;
}

h2, video, h3 {
display: inline-block;
width: 30%;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to wrap your elements inside a `div` conatiner and and CSS to this `div`.

CSS/HTML:

```css
div#container{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

video{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  vertical-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h2 id="vtitle">Some Title</h2>
  <video src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" controls></video>
  <h3 id="vdescription">Some Description</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I want the video to be in the exact center, and no matter the size of the title and comments, the video will always be in the exact center and the title and description to either side.

Comment: @user3042719 Gotcha. Checkout my updated answer above. Hope it helps :) EDIT: Updated again to include `%` instead of `px` in the CSS part.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you still didn't really understand. Kapantazak got it though. Sorry for my lack of skills to describe this, I couldn't really figure out how to describe what I wanted correctly. Thanks anyway!